# How to filter Tensorflow TextLineDataset by length of text

Tags: python, tensorflow, pipeline

I want filter as 3 <= length_of_text <=15 but i couldn't this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset("data.txt")


def drop_outliers(line):

    return (3<= tf.size(line) <=15).numpy()

dataset = dataset.filter(lambda line: tf.py_function(func = drop_outliers,
                                                inp=[line],
                                                Tout = tf.bool))

iterator = iter(dataset)
print(iterator.get_next())
```

I got "end of sequence" error when run this code.

Answer (score 0):

In the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Iterator#get_next) for `Iterator.get_next()`, you'll see that an `OutOfRangeError` when the end of the sequence is reached,

> Raises `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError`: If the end of the iterator has been reached.

So, the error is not because of `TextLineDataset` or `dataset.filter()`. You may use `dataset.as_numpy_iterator()` like,

```
out = list( dataset.as_numpy_iterator() )
```

Or surround the `dataset.get_next()` method with `try except` block,

```
for i in range( seq_length ):
   try:
       element = iterator.get_next()
   except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
       print( "End of sequence reached" )
       break
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i want filter by length of text between 3 and 15. How do this?